# Creating a custom validation across two HMT associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I have two `HMT` associations. The first is between my `Artist` and `Album` models, basically signifying that multiple artists can belong to an album. The other association is setup between my `Artist` and `Track` models via `TrackFeature`. The purpose of this association is add a *featured artist* to a track.

I'd like to setup a validation that none of the possible album artists cannot be featured artists on any tracks pertaining to that particular album. I know that this validation would need to be on the join model. The problem is that what I have now doesn't seem to work. What do I need to change in order for this to successfully validate?

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :albums, through: :album_artists

  has_many :track_features
  has_many :tracks, through: :track_features
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :artists, through: :album_artists
end

class AlbumArtist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :track_features
  has_many :featured_artists, through: :track_features

  belongs_to :album
end

class TrackFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :track
  belongs_to :featured_artist, class_name: "Artist", foreign_key: :artist_id

  validate :track_artist

  private
    def track_artist
      if track.album.artists.exists?(name: artist.name)
        track.errors[:base] << "Album artist cannot be a featured artist"
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: I would investigate this using **pry-rails** **gem** by adding `binding.pry` in the top of `track_artist` `method` and figure out what's wrong